# Is there a way to get rid of this null pointer exception I am geting?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, tooltip

The following code shows a null pointer exception

```
private void _settooltip() {
    localXYLineAndShapeRenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new XYToolTipGenerator() {
        @Override
        public String generateToolTip(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item) {
                //String toolTip = getToolTipText();
                   // return toolTip;
            CurveSegment segment = (CurveSegment) curveEncapsulator.getSegment(currentCurve);
            if (segment != null) {
                segment.getA();
                segment.getB();
                segment.getC();
            }


            double A = segment.getA();
            double B = segment.getB();
            double C = segment.getC();


            String AA = String.valueOf(A);
            String BB = String.valueOf(B);
            String CC = String.valueOf(C);


            return "A = " + AA + " B = " + BB + " C = " + CC;



        }
    });
}
```

I am getting exception on

public String generateToolTip(XYDataset dataset, int series, int item)

Can anyone tell me how to handle this null pointer exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can be about "segment", You can try sthg like this;

```
        double A = 0;
        double B =  0;
        double C =  0;

        String AA =  "";
        String BB =  "";
        String CC =  "";

        if (segment != null) {
            A = segment.getA();
            B = segment.getB();
            C = segment.getC();

            AA = String.valueOf(A);
            BB = String.valueOf(B);
            CC = String.valueOf(C);
        }
```

if you share stck trace we can help better.

Answer (score 0):

I can just guess that `localXYLineAndShapeRenderer` is null. Please show us a code that initializes this variable if it exists.

Comment: private DynUnitSplinerenderer localXYLineAndShapeRenderer = new DynUnitSplinerenderer(50) {

        @Override
        public void setCurrentSeriesUnit(int series, String unit) {
            super.setCurrentSeriesUnit(series, unit); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            _updateCurveUnitWhenRendererUnitChanged();
        }

    };

Comment: This code is not readable. Please edit you post and add formatted code there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this :

```
        CurveSegment segment = (CurveSegment) curveEncapsulator.getSegment(currentCurve);
        if (segment != null) {
            segment.getA();
            segment.getB();
            segment.getC();
        }
```

You expect `segment` to sometimes be null.

However, you still call these :

```
        double A = segment.getA();
        double B = segment.getB();
        double C = segment.getC();
```

Without checking that `segment` is not null.

Actually, the code inside the if statement makes no sense, since you do nothing with the returned values of the method calls.